# ng2-bootstrap issues with Typescript 2

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I have installed and added **ng2-bootstrap** in an **angular2** project, but I have compilation errors.
It seemes to be linked to **Typescript 2** as if I had the bad version configured in my package.json, but it is not the case, look at it:

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.2",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.21",

    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25",

    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.1.14-1",
  },

"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2"
    },
"repository": {}
}
```

Error example for line:

```
private readonly trueValue;
```

Errors:

```
Duplicate identifier 'readonly'.
Cannot find name 'trueValue'.
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Provide some of this errors, please.

Comment: private readonly trueValue;

what this line should do?
Shouldn't it be like: private variableName: Type; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself.
It was a noob issue.
Visual Studio 2015 was not up-to-date because I still was in TypeScript 1.8 version.

After the update, everything rocks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error as well, and in my case it was a consequence of my local installation of typescript still being an earlier version, while the global version had been updated to 2.1.0.  Once I specified the latest version in package.json the issue was resolved.